# convert "DD/MM/YYYY h:m" to timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I need to convert `DD/MM/YYYY h:m` eg 21/12/2015 17:14 this date to timestamp format using php and store it in mysql.

I have tried `strtotime()` and some other functions but it's not working. Can any one help me on this. I'm using datepicker to generate the value for date time

Comment: `strtotime()` recognises formats using a `/` separator as US format, and a `-` as UK/European format, as [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects instead, and you can use [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php); and you can use [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) with the `U` format string to get the unix timestamp

Comment: `$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $myOriginalDateString)->format('U')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to convert "DD/MM/YYYY h:m" into timestamp

```
$dateString = "21/12/2015 17:14";
$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $dateString));
```

Comment: We can use DateTime also but it is one of the way to solve this

Comment: strtotime('d/m/Y H:i','21-12-2015 17:14');

Comment: No my dear frnd it will error "A non well formed numeric value encountered" Please try it

Comment: you are right doing stupid thing, actually want to share this: echo date('d/m/Y H:i',"21-12-2015 17:14:00"); your answer is 100% correct deserve for upvote

Answer (score 1):

you can use DateTime class:

```
$dateStr = '21/12/2015 17:14';
echo $timestamp = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dateStr)->getTimestamp();
```